# How to Remove Disable Product from Cart

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer

I want to delete the Disable product completely, through **Observer**! Programatically
Like if we have a Disable Product, We have to delete it.

> Product is disabled an event is triggered and remove that product from
>   customers cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a Test Module, in which create these files**

> etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="custom_customer_log_login" instance="Example\New\Observer\UpdateCartAfterCustomerLoginAtObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

> observer/UpdateCartAfterCustomerLoginAtObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace Example\Test\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface ;

class UpdateCartAfterCustomerLoginAtObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    protected $_customerCartSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
     */
    protected $_productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_productModel;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
     */
    public function __construct
    (
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
    ){
        $this->_customerCartSession = $cart;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_productModel = $productModel;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){

        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $cartItems = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
            $product = $this->_productModel->load($item->getProductId());
            if(!$product->getStatus())
                $this->_customerCartSession->removeItem($item->getItemId())->save();
        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

**This is work for me:)**